# Bootstrap v3.2.0 Modal iFrame not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap modal with iFrame works fine in all browsers if I load youtube videos.

I am trying to open PDF documents. I am able to load PDF documents in IE and Chrome but this example is **not working in Firefox.**

Here is the working example of trying to load a PDF document:

**http://jsfiddle.net/2AU6q/147/**

**Works fine in all browsers except Mozilla Firefox.**

Currently my work around in using jQuery UI Dialog as its loading PDF in all browsers.

Please let me know if there is any solution to make bootstrap modal work in Firefox.

**Modal html:**

```
<div class="container"> <a class="modalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-src="http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" data-height=320 data-width=450 data-target="#myModal">Click me</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**JS:**

```
$('a.modalButton').on('click', function (e) {
var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
var height = $(this).attr('data-height') || 300;
var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 400;

$("#myModal iframe").attr({
    'src': src,
        'height': height,
        'width': width
});
});
```

Comment: works here, can you open your console and check for errors?

Comment: you are able to get it working on Firefox ?

Comment: Yes, i get the Modal Dialog in your fiddle in my Firefox, try disabling some addons like Firebug.

Comment: i can view the video properly, but i am facing the same problem with bootstrap modal.